# SQL Selecting Two Tables

Tags: sql

I dont know how to write the select statement to get the information about details of intervention with only the student id.

If the student id is 2. I would want to find the information about intervention named MENTORING.

### student_intervention table

```
id   student_id inter_details_id   start_date                   end_date         staff_id
 1      2          1            2029-09-12 00:00:00     2029-10-12 00:00:00 0
 2      2          1            2029-09-12 00:50:00     2029-10-12 00:00:00 0
```

### intervention_details

```
   id      name           description
    1      MENTORING      MENTORING2
    2      BESPOKE        BESPOKE
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, staff_id
FROM student_intervention, intervention_details
WHERE student_intervention.inter_details_id = intervention_details.id
And student_intervention.student_id = 2
And intervention_details.name = 'MENTORING'
```

This doesn't use 'inner join' syntax, but should still work

Comment: In a column description there is no value 'MENTORING'